# binomial/factorial identity mod p

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

In trying to determine the spectrum of a well-known ergodic transformation, I came up with the following useful (for me) result.

Let $p$ be a prime and $a$ a positive integer. Then for $M$ a positive integer, we have
$$
{{M} \choose {p^a}} \equiv {\rm floor}\left(\frac M{p^a} \right) \mod p.
$$
[The thing on the left is supposed to represent $M$ choose $p^a$, and the right side is supposed to be the floor of $M/p^a$, but on my screen, it looks confusing.]

I have a tedious argument for this (which is probably correct), but why re-invent the binomial wheel? This identity must be known. Can someone provide a reference?

Comment: See Lucas's Theorem.

Comment: Do you know of Kummer's theorem (or Lucas's theorem) on binomial coefficients?  I think it would be a consequence of one of those.  Gerhard "Don't Have A Literature Reference" Paseman, 2015.07.01

Comment: If p^a divides M, this is easy. Just let C_M be the cyclic group of order M and let G be the p^a element subgroup.  Then G acts on the p^a element subsets if C_M and the fixed points of G are its cosets. So it follows from the fact that the number of fixed points of a p-group acting on a set is congruent to the size of the set mod p. I don't know if this idea can be adapted to the general case.

Comment: Right, Lucas' theorem yields it immediately. The proof below is good, too. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, don't know a reference, but here is a quick argument.

If $M=p^ab+c$ with $0\leq c\leq p^a-1$, then 
$$(1+x)^M=(1+x)^{p^ab}(1+x)^c
=(1+x^{p^a})^b(1+x)^c
\mod p.
$$
In turn, this equals
$$
(1+bx^{p^a} + ...)(1+x)^c \mod p
$$
where $...$ means higher degree terms. Since $c<p^a$, there is no further 
correction after multiplying by $(1+x)^c$ (the coefficient by $x^{p^a}$ stays $b$), and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

As for references, you may want to give a look at the introduction and Section 2.2 of R. Meštrović's survey/preprint on Lucas's theorem ([on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3820)).